# Capifony (Capistrano) asks for github credentials when trying to deploy Symfony2 app

Tags: symfony, github, capistrano, composer-php, capifony

I am trying to put my website in production with capifony (capistrano) symfony2 app

Everything goes well but at some point it asks about Github credentials for private repos.

here is my error

> [out :: web-dev.domain.com] Could not fetch
>   https://api.github.com/repos/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle/zipball/4a2c803dc8db79952ad5e71783c16178427bbc02,
>   enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos ** [out ::
>   web-dev.domain.com] The credentials will be swapped for an OAuth token
>   stored in /home/webdev/.composer/config.json, your password will not
>   be stored ** [out :: web-dev.domain.com] To revoke access to this
>   token you can visit https://github.com/settings/applications  [out ::
>   web-dev.domain.com] Username:

When I enter my username and press enter, nothing happened just goes to new line. Is there any solution for this problem?

This solved my problem:

```
https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding
```

Comment: I think you should read this https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys

Comment: I saw that, but didn't help :(

Comment: Have you tried to type your password after pressing Enter ?

Comment: Yes, but it wont work. Just goes to new line

Comment: Probably you are using `https` protocol instead of `git` in repository URL?

Comment: @thecatontheflat that works for me, thanks. you should create your own answer!

Comment: Maybe you stumbled upon the following issue which was solved a month ago: https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/3651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem running composer install (not with capifony).

The fix I found was explained here: https://coderwall.com/p/xanheg

It seems sensio has renamed their repo from sensio to sensiolabs. So I:

- removed the vendors/sensio folder
- in composer.lock renamed all instances of https://github.com/sensio to https://github.com/sensiolabs, and https://api.github.com/repos/sensio to https://api.github.com/repos/sensiolabs

Ran composer install and all worked correctly

Answer (score 1):

To avoid interactive (but disruptive) credentials ask, you can add this line in your `deploy.rb` file :

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

It transfers your SSH key for github access.

Comment: I have forward_agent = true but doesn help